# htaccess selective forwarding

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

This is somewhat of a unique question that I cant seem to find the answer for anywhere! I am new to playing with htaccess files. Here's what im trying to do, let me know if this is at all possible:

I am trying to redirect when someone access a certain directory DIRECTLY, however, my server needs the ability to access the directory to initiate file downloads.

Here's what I am using to accomplish the redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../ [NC]
```

It works like a charm, however when my script tries to access the filesystem it naturally gets redirected as well.

The purpose of this is protected file downloads. The user's access downloads via a protected area and the download link is similar to http://example.com/download/superlongidhash

This URL is then taken and read by the script, formulates the actual path to the file and sends php header's accordingly:

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-length: ".filesize($path)); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($path) . ""); 
readfile($path);
```

Any help would be much appreciated :) If there is a better way to do this, let me know!

FYI, this is all within the CodeIgniter framework

Comment: "script tries to access the filesystem" what specifically are you doing?

Comment: Meant to include that. Added the PHP above. It's just forcing a download of the file.

Comment: @Jeremy Is `$path` a local path, or a URL? Not sure how the `.htaccess` would effect access to the file on the local file system.

Comment: You could place the files in a directory above the htdocs (public folder), so PHP can access it, but the public cannot?

Comment: Also, you could use UNIX directory permissions to prevent public read access.

Comment: @Tim, its a relative path. I'm trying to prevent direct access without limiting the ability to force an authorized download.

Comment: @Alex hmm, completely forgot about moving it out of the public directory. I think that's what I'll do. Thanks guys, I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the http_referrer is the one for your site. If it's not, you redirect the user to your homepage (or wherever you want).

Take a look into this article I found about doing exactly what you want.
http://www.dialme.com/m/articles/view/How-to-Prevent-direct-access-to-files-and-folders

I hope this helps.

Comment: Spoofing a referrer is trivial. It's inadvisable to attempt to authenticate users with `http_referrer`.